# os.listdir() return weird Korean value (encoding issue)

Tags: python, unicode, listdir

I have folders and its name includes few Korean characters.

When I read list of folder name by `os.listdir`,
its name value is purely different with normal string.

Example:

- one korean folder name from os.listdir() : "누" = (`\xe1\x84\x82\xe1\x85\xae`)
- pure string "누" in python console = (`\xeb\x88\x84`)

What makes difference?
We can estimate it is from `os.listdir()` gives confusing with some encoding..

Comment: might be useful to know what OS you're on, I'd assume this makes a difference

Answer (score 2):

Both of these are the same encoding (UTF-8), but...

> "누" = (\xe1\x84\x82\xe1\x85\xae)

This represents the character as composed of the two jamo (the 24 building blocks of the Korean (hangeul) alphabet):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> x = b'\xe1\x84\x82'.decode('utf-8')
>>> y = b'\xe1\x85\xae'.decode('utf-8')
>>> unicodedata.name(x)
'HANGUL CHOSEONG NIEUN'
>>> unicodedata.name(y)
'HANGUL JUNGSEONG U'
```

> "누" in python console = (\xeb\x88\x84)

Whereas when you actually type the character in a console window, you (apparently) get a precomposed character:

```
>>> z = b'\xeb\x88\x84'.decode('utf-8')
>>> unicodedata.name(z)
'HANGUL SYLLABLE NU'
```

Comment: Great. that's right answer!! Then I need to find some mehthod how can i merge into one character.